# Finding the smallest DFA that separates two words without using brute force search?

Tags: finite-automata

Given two strings a and b, I want to build a minimum size DFA that accepts a and rejects b. One way to do this is brute force search.
Is there an alternative? If so, what is it?

Comment: Welcome. What is your current alternative? See [ask] to help provide a complete question.

Comment: I suspect that this is homework of some sort so the usual question is: **what have you tried so far?**

Comment: What you actually trying to convey ?